What does "going over" mean here?

Even good restaurants can fail to turn a profit with so many offerings going over a relatively fixed pool of dining spend.

The Standard
What does it mean?

Source? Is the sentence from a dictionary? Is it from a newspaper article?

Among many news sites covering the story: MSN and Propel Info

That is a meaningless sentence. What is a "relatively fixed pool of dining spend"? That looks like a random string.

OP inquired about the meaning of  "going over" in the sentence:

Even good restaurants can fail to turn a profit with so many offerings  going over a relatively fixed pool of dining spend.

It became clear after searching that the dictionary meanings of "going over" (e.g., reviewing or crossing) do not apply here. Instead, the sentence should be broken down as follows:

"[So many offerings going]": "Going" here means existing, available, to be had . It refers to the fact that there are many restaurants or dining options available.
"[Over a relatively fixed pool]": This describes how these offerings are spread out or competing for a limited resource—in this case, the fixed amount of money people spend on dining.

When combined, the phrase suggests that there are many dining options competing for a relatively small, fixed amount of spending.
[Hence even good restaurants can fail to turn a profit]
In this context, the usage reflects the same meaning as 'fighting for a piece of the pie,' where multiple parties compete for a share of something limited, such as profits or resources.

a piece/slice/share of the pie.
idiom mainly US (UK usually a piece/slice of the cake)
part of the profit or benefit from something, or part of the amount of something that is available:

Source: Cambridge dictionary

Thank you,James, for the good explanation.

@jiongxiazhu - This explanation makes sense, but FYI it's a very poorly written sentence. I can quickly think of three simple edits that would improve it. The newspaper probably fired all their copy-editors.

@JonathanZ It's a news item and it appeared in The Standard and other newspapers under the title:
London fine dining restaurant "churn" accelerates as costs and tax burden rises ever higher.
As it was spoken by Harden’s London Restaurants
co-founder and editor, he would have to fire himself.
